# PHP Registration Form Not Showing Users in The Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, registration

I created a form with HTML and then a form which is supposed to send the information to a mySQL database. The information doesn't show up in the database though. What am I doing wrong?

This is my HTML:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
                                <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" class="sign-up-input" value="<?php echo $fn; ?>"><br>
                                <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" class="sign-up-input" value="<?php echo $ln; ?>"><br>
                                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" class="sign-up-input" value="<?php echo $un; ?>"><br>
                                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" class="sign-up-input" value="<?php echo $em; ?>"><br>
                                <input type="text" name="email2" placeholder="Repeat E-mail" class="sign-up-input" value="<?php echo $em2; ?>"><br>
                                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="sign-up-input"><br>
                                <input type="password" name="password2" placeholder="Repeat Password" class="sign-up-input"><br>
                                <input type="submit" name="reg" value="Sign Up">
                            </form>
```

This is my PHP:

```
    <?php include ("inc/scripts/mysql_connect.inc.php");  
$reg = @$_POST['reg'];
//declaring variable to prevent errors
$fn = ""; //first name
$ln = ""; //last name
$un = ""; //username
$em = ""; //email
$em2 = ""; // email repeated
$pswd = ""; //password
$pswd2 = ""; //pasword repeated
$u_check = ""; //check username
$fn = strip_tags(@$_POST['fname']);
$ln = strip_tags(@$_POST['lname']);
$un = strip_tags(@$_POST['username']);
$em = strip_tags(@$_POST['email']);
$em2 = strip_tags(@$_POST['email2']);
$pswd = strip_tags(@$_POST['password']);
$pswd2 = strip_tags(@$_POST['password2']);
$d = date("Y-m-d"); //year month day
if ($reg) {
  if ($em==$em2) {
    $u_check = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$un'");
    $check = mysql_num_rows($u_check);
    $e_check = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$em'");
    $email_check = mysql_num_rows($e_check);
      if ($check == 0) {
        if ($email_check == 0) {
          if ($fn && $ln && $un && $em && $em2 && $pswd && $pswd2) {
            if ($pswd == $pswd2) {
              if (strlen($un)>25||strlen($fn)>25||strlen($ln)>25) {
                echo "<br><br><br><br>The maximum limit for username/first name/last name is 25 characters!";
              } else {
                if (strlen($pswd)>30||strlen($pswd)<5) {
                  echo "<br><br><br><br>Your password must be between 5 and 30 characters long!";
                } else {
                  $pswd = md5($pswd);
                  $pswd2 = md5($pswd2);
                  $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('','$un','$fn','$ln','$em','$pswd','$d','0','Write something about yourself.','','','no')");
                  die("Welcome to findFriends Login to your account to get started...");
                }
              }
            } else {
              echo "Your passwords don't match!";
            }
          } else {
          echo "Please fill in all of the fields";
          }
        } else {
        echo "Sorry, but it looks like someone has already used that email!";
        }
      } else {
      echo "Username already taken ...";
      }
    } else {
    echo "Your E-mails don't match!";
    }
  }
?>
```

And this is my mySQL connect code:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","", "socialnetwork") or die("no such user exists!");
mysql_select_db("socialnetwork") or die("no such database exists!");
echo "Connected to database";
?>
```

My website doesn't display any errors but the database doesn't show any users. What did I do wrong?

*DISCLAIMER - I found this code on a youtube tutorial. When he did it it worked. Heres the video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCr9TthDtxk

Comment: Here's something not in the YouTube video `echo mysql_error();`. That guy did so many things wrong it's not even funny. Post your DB error and we can go from there.

Comment: This is by far the worst registration form I have ever seen. Why don't you use anothere reference rather than such bad tutorial

Comment: I'm new to PHP and mySQL so I can't debug it myself. :( . I'm not getting any errors. It's just not sending any of the inputs to my database and my database appears blank. It shows the success page (Welcome to findFriends Login to your account to get started...) but nothing appears in the DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
//change this
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('','$un','$fn','$ln','$em','$pswd','$d','0','Write something about yourself.','','','no')");

//to

$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username, fname, lname, email, password, date, about) VALUES ('$un','$fn','$ln','$em','$pswd','$d','Write something about yourself.')");
```

instead of adding all data for field. define your field besides the table name then set values correspond to the field defined to be inserted.

also, in database set your id in "auto increment"